# SMB/CIFS Port Forwarding MyBook World Edition

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, smb, cifs, mybook

I have a WD MyBook World Edition NAS that i try to use as a Shared Network Drive through the Internet. I set up DynDns and forwarded Ports 21 and 548 for FTP and AFP access, which both work like a charm.

But now to the problem: I also want to access the Drive on Windows machines, so after some reading i learned that the corresponding protocol for that is SMB/CIFS and that i need to forward port 445 for SMB and ports 137-139 for NetBIOS stuff (which i don't really understand). So i did that, but it doesn't seem to work.

Are those the wrong ports? Or am is just trying to access it the wrong way? I tried it by "Mount Network Drive.." and then entering "smb://mydyndnsadress/sharedfolder"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not wrong ports but I don't think many will try to perform this over the internet. SMB is not an encrypted protocol and IMHO not inherently secure to be hosted on internet either. I am not sure how are we authenticating to these shares but kerb is certainly not gona work. Netbios hosting ports 137 138 UDP and 139 TCP are renowned for security issues.

Plus CIFS natting is not going to help if multiple users are going to access this share.

I would suggest to probably consider a VPN kind of solution than performing a NAT in this specific case.